# Strange behavior with MainWindow.xib, app will not reach didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ios-simulator

I've started a new project in Xcode 3.2.5 where everything is being done in code. I don't want to use xibs this time though am looking forward to an integrated IB in Xcode 4.

The problem came up when I edited a string in a json file. On running the code I noticed the old string appearing even though the file was certainly changed, so I deleted my `Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` folder, expecting that my json changes would then be loaded to the bundle and the code would then see the expected value.

Then command-Y to build and run and it wouldn't run. Although there is no MainWindow.xib in my project folder my Info.plist file refers to MainWindow.xib. (I removed it, following the creation of this iPhone app with Xcode's New Project template) So I removed that key from the plist figuring the xib must have been sitting around in the app bundle after being installed in the simulator the first time I ran the app.

Then I ran the app again. No complaints, only a black screen - and a breakpoint in my app delegate, on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not being hit.

I have not changed anything in main.m. How can it be that the app is not launching?

Comment: Did you use to have `MainWindow.xib` before problems started happening?  Sometimes Xcode caches resources so if you deleted MainWindow it might think it's still there.  When you reset the simulator it effectively cleaned Xcode, maybe triggering a problem.

Comment: That seems correct - what I want to do is get it to not want the xib at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something got messed up when you removed `MainWindow.xib`.  Try these steps to see if it'll correct the problem.

1. Under the Project menu, choose `Edit Active Target`. Select the Properties tab and blank out the Main Nib File field. Close the Target Info window.
2. Under the Other Sources group and edit the main.m file. In the UIApplicationMain function call, change the last parameter to the name of your application delegate class.

   ```
   int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
   ```
3. In your application delegate you need to create a window object. I do this in -applicationDidFinishLaunching:. If you defined anything else in your MainWindow.xib, you can probably create that here, too.

   ```
   - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
   {
   UIWindow *appWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   self.window = appWindow;
   [appWindow release];
   }
   ```

If this doesn't work, let me know and I can give you another way.

Comment: I had figured out setting the app delegate in main() but not creating a window - thanks! I get no analyzer warning either way but I assume once self.window is assigned, the window variable should be released same as with a view controller's assignment to self.view, in loadView?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but every app **must** contain a window.  Without it nothing could display on the screen.  There is only *one* window in each app, and it contains views. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you dont have a `view` connected in the XIB.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as @"AppDelegate" but you can write like this too :

```
(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]))
```

Comment: Xcode's refactoring support will work correctly with this code.